# Remove Day Names from filenames with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a small Bash script to remove Day Names from PDF file names. For example, I want to rename:

```
newspaper20240204-sunday_01.pdf
newspaper20240204-sunday_02.pdf
newspaper20240204-sunday_03.pdf
newspaper20240204-sunday_04.pdf
newspaper20240204-sunday_05.pdf
newspaper20240205-monday_01.pdf
newspaper20240205-monday_02.pdf
newspaper20240205-monday_03.pdf
newspaper20240205-monday_04.pdf
newspaper20240205-monday_05.pdf
```

to

```
newspaper20240204_01.pdf
newspaper20240204_02.pdf
newspaper20240204_03.pdf
newspaper20240204_04.pdf
newspaper20240204_05.pdf
newspaper20240205_01.pdf
newspaper20240205_02.pdf
newspaper20240205_03.pdf
newspaper20240205_04.pdf
newspaper20240205_05.pdf
```

I'm new to Bash, so be gentle :] Thank you for any help.

Comment: `rename -n 's/[a-z]*?day_//' *.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the scheme is always `something-dayofweek_num.pdf -> something_num.pdf` you can try:

```
for f in *-*_*.pdf; do mv "$f" "${f%-*}_${f##*_}"; done
```

Explanation: `${f%-*}` is one of the many parameter substitutions. It expands as the value of bash variable `f` with the final part from the last `-` removed. `${f##*_}` is another that expands as the value of bash variable `f` with the longest prefix, up to the last `_`, removed.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Renaud Pacalet, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here the script I wrote for you:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for OLD_FILE in *.pdf; do
    NEW_FILE=$(echo "${OLD_FILE}" | sed -r "s:(.+)-.+(_[0-9]+\..+):\1\2:")
    mv -v "${OLD_FILE}" "${NEW_FILE}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Antonio Petrica. I've tried the script. But unfortunately, only the words -sunday or -monday should have been deleted, but the numbers _01, _02, _03, _04, _05 were also deleted. So the files overwrite each other and finally there is one file left. Which part should we fix so that the number in the file name is not deleted?

Comment: Very strange. I reproduced your scenario and it worked for me.

Comment: After I tried again, it now works fine. Thank You. Now there are two ways and they work fine.